# Printf sendo executada duas vezes durante um loop

Tags: c

Estou criando um protótipo de jogo da forca. Não entendo muito de programação e estou com um problema em relação ao que é retornado. A parte do código que está dando problema e que está abaixo me retorna duas vezes o "Digite uma letra: ". Alguém sabe me dizer o motivo?

```
  for(chance = 1; chance <= 10; chance++)
       {
        printf("\n");
        printf("Digite uma letra: ");
        scanf("%c", &letra);
        printf("\n");
        for(i = 0;word[i] != '\0';i++)
        {
            if(letra == word[i])
            {
                var[i*2] = letra;
            }
        }
        printf("%s\n", var);
```

[image: Retorno]

Answer (score 1):

Se você colocar um `printf("%d",chance);` no seu loop, vai ver que ele é executado duas vezes a cada caractere que você coloca, ou seja, o `scanf` está executando duas vezes com um caractere. Isso se dá porque quando você digita, por exemplo, a letra `'a'`, logo depois precisa apertar enter, então na verdade ele lê **dois** caracteres, um `'a'` e um `'\n'`. Como seu `scanf` só lê um caractere, o `'\n'` que vem depois é salvo no buffer para ser lido posteriormente, ou seja, na próxima iteração do loop. Quando vem o próximo `scanf`, ele lê o `\n`. É por isso que ele executa duas vezes.

Pra resolver esse problema, coloque um espaço antes do `%c` do seu `scanf`, exatamente dessa forma: `scanf(" %c", &letra);`. Assim o seu `'\n'` é "lido" pelo caractere vazio. Meus testes rodaram corretamente aqui.